# Generate json file with single slash by python

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have a json file as below, in which the value of `geometry` is a string. 
I need to add a single slash in front of each double quote inside the string
from:

```
{"geometry": 
  "{"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[25.4907, 35.29833],[25.49187, 35.28897]]}"
}
```

to:

```
{"geometry": 
  "{\"type\": \"LineString\", \"coordinates\": [[25.4907, 35.29833], [25.49187, 35.28897]]}"}
```

I tried to achieved this by using `replace` before exporting by `json` library

```
obj['geometry'] = str(feat['geometry']).replace("'","\\'")

with open(json_filepath, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(map(json.dumps, data)))
```

but the output is double slash:

```
"geometry": "{\\"type\\": \\"MultiPolygon\\", \\"coordinates\\":
...
```

How to generate a file with one slash only, thanks~

---- edited

Adding example of source data:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            121.51749976660096,
            25.04609631049641
          ],
          [
            121.51870845722954,
            25.045781689873138
          ],
          [
            121.51913536000893,
            25.045696164346566
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "model": {
          "RoadClass": "3",
          "RoadClassName": "省道一般道路",
          "RoadID": "300010",
          "RoadName": "臺1線",
          "RoadNameID": "10",
          "InfoDate": "2015-04-01T00:00:00"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            121.51913536000893,
            25.045696164346566
          ],
          [
            121.51938079578713,
            25.045646605406546
          ],
          [
            121.51946871710766,
            25.0456288491921
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "model": {
          "RoadClass": "3",
          "RoadClassName": "省道一般道路",
          "RoadID": "300010",
          "RoadName": "臺1線",
          "RoadNameID": "10",
          "InfoDate": "2015-04-01T00:00:00"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The original data is in geojson format from an API. what I'm going to do for this data is to insert it into Bigquery in a `Geography` data type, with reference from [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-load-geojson-files-into-bigquery-gis-9dc009802fb4).

According to the blog, I need to:

1. Extract values in `features`
2. Change data type in `geometry` to string
3. Add slash before each comma in `geometry` string

Comment: BTW this is not forward slash... This one is -> `/`

Comment: _I have a json file as below_  - where does this malformed JSON comes from in the first place? You should be fixing it there, at the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment, the json you give can't used directly in Python (neither in a json file). Thus, I decide to use it as a Python dictionary.

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path

dict_to_put_as_json = {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [[25.4907, 35.29833], [25.49187, 35.28897]],
    }
}

geometry_as_string = json.dumps(dict_to_put_as_json["geometry"])
dict_to_write = {"geometry": geometry_as_string}

with Path("result.json").open(mode="w") as fp:
    json.dump(dict_to_write, fp)
```

Like this, it gives in the json file:

```json
{
  "geometry": "{\"type\": \"LineString\", \"coordinates\": [[25.4907, 35.29833], [25.49187, 35.28897]]}"
}
```